# PhaserJS: Animation objects dropping out and reappearing during animation

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have a loop * 20 creating tweens of a set of randomly selected png (they're simple boxes for the moment). After creation, they do a simple X-axis sliding animation.

During the animations, some of the boxes will disappear/pop out. Later on, as the tweens are completing, some will reappear/pop in.

Did I miss something to keep them from popping out? I have onStart/onComplete events and they fire when they're supposed to, so it would seem that whatever pops out isn't completing early, only being removed from display.

*(I attempted jsfiddle/codepen, but the script didn't work at all)*

Here's the code:

```
<head>
<script src="phaser.min.js"></script>
<script>
const config = {
    preload: preload,
    create: create,
    update: update
};

const game = new Phaser.Game(1280, 480, Phaser.auto, '', config)

function preload () {
    game.load.image('qtrf', 'img/quarter_0000_quarter-fade.png');
    game.load.image('qtr', 'img/quarter_0003_quarter.png');
    game.load.image('halff', 'img/half_0001_half-fade.png');
    game.load.image('half', 'img/half_0004_half.png');
    game.load.image('fullf', 'img/full-fade.png');
    game.load.image('full', 'img/full.png');

}

function create () {
    game.stage.backgroundColor = "#90cfc7";

    const bars = [
        // field 1 = name of sprite and sprite definition
        // field 2 = drop rate for random picking
        {"qtr": game.add.sprite(-160,0, 'qtr'), "rate": 15 },
        {"qtrf": game.add.sprite(-160,0, 'qtrf'), "rate": 2},
        {"half": game.add.sprite(-320,0, 'half'), "rate": 20},
        {"halff": game.add.sprite(-320,0, 'halff'), "rate": 2},
        {"full": game.add.sprite(-640,0, 'full'), "rate": 5},
        {"fullf": game.add.sprite(-640,0, 'fullf'), "rate": 5}
    ];

    const barrates = [];
    const barsprites = [];
    bars.forEach(element => {
        barrates.push(element.rate);
        Object.entries(element).forEach(objE => {
            if (objE[0] != "rate") {
                barsprites.push(objE[1]);
            }
        });
    });
    let ratesum = barrates.reduce((a,b) => a+b, 0)
            ratetable = barrates.map(e => (Number.parseFloat(e / ratesum).toFixed(2)) * 100);

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        let randbar = game.rnd.between(1, 100);
        let randtime = game.rnd.between(5000, 20000);
        let randdelay = game.rnd.between(2000, 10000);
        let position = 0;
        for (let j = 0; j < ratetable.length; j++) {
            position += ratetable[j]
            if (randbar < position+1) {
                console.log(j, randtime, randdelay);
                game.add.tween(barsprites[j]).to({ x: game.width }, randtime, Phaser.Easing.Linear.None, true, randdelay, -1, true);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

function update () {
}

function getbar () {

}

    </script>

</head>
```

Comment: Hi, a couple of questions, (i) any errors visible in the console? (ii) when they pop back in, are they popping back in in the position they were initialized in or the position they are supposed to go to?  You may want to hardwire in values for their paths for testing so you know what the animation "should" be.